# Sorting Database Records in Descending Order

Tags: database, vb.net, sorting, listbox, ado

I'm relatively New To programming and VB and Would like some help. I am trying to list runners in the order of their speed (Fastest First), the data is from a database, i am able to sort the data in ascending order but cannot get them in descending order, is there a way to do that simply, if not what is the simplest way to reverse the Listboxes.

My Code At the Moment:

```
Private Sub RunningRanking()
    Dim DBconn As New ADODB.Connection 'This is a connection string   declaration'
    Dim Record As New ADODB.Recordset ' This is a connection to the record
    DBconn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data source = '" & Application.StartupPath & "\Users Database.mdb'") 'this is opening the connection between the 
    'system and database
    With Record
        .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        .Open("Trainee", DBconn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        .Sort = "RunningSpeed" 'sorting the database record in ascending order
        Do Until Record.EOF
            LstBoxName.Items.Add(Record.Fields("First Name").Value)
            LstBoxSpeed.Items.Add(Record.Fields("RunningSpeed").Value)
            .MoveNext()
        Loop
    End With
    Record.Close()
    DBconn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use ADODB.Recordset instead of "table". Then you'll be able to sort data via SQL query: `SELECT <FieldList> FROM Trainee ORDER BY RunningSpeed DESC;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `desc` keyword to sort the data descending:

```
.Sort = "RunningSpeed desc"
```

Consider using an SQL query to fetch the data instead of opening the table. The database is generally much faster at sorting the data than the `Recordset` object.

Comment: Great minds think the same. See my comment to the question ;)

Comment: How would i do that, What Decelerations would i need to make and are there any references i need to add, I've Used the Recordset Object because its both easy and logical to me, and I've already used it throughout my System/Program, any more help would be appreciated, Thanks for  answering the original question it helped a lot.

Comment: @LMansour: You can still use the `Recordset` object, but using an SQL query instead of the table name. Use `adOpenForwardOnly` and `adLockReadOnly` to use a minimum of resources to read the result. Example: `.Open("select [First Name], RunningSpeed from Trainee order by RunningSpeed desc", ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)`